# Feeds: how to populate a 'File' field from a path/filename in csv file?

Tags: nodes, feeds, files, importing-exporting

I've got a csv file I'm using the Feeds module to convert to nodes.  It's going pretty well, but I have many documents (max of 1 per node, though) that need to be associated with my nodes.

I have the filename in the csv file (and can easily prepend any path necessary), but I'm having trouble figuring out if/how it is possible to get Feeds to match up the files.

Comment: Definitely seems possible, [`FeedsFileFetcher::fetch()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21feeds%21plugins%21FeedsFileFetcher.inc/function/FeedsFileFetcher%3A%3Afetch/7) looks a likely candidate. Not sure how you invoke that though

Comment: Yup, use a file systems path (`public://path/filename.ext`). Your file must exist before import and be accessible to the apache user. The [feeds_tamper module](https://drupal.org/project/feeds_tamper‎) is a great way to prepend this path to a filename.